# Assign image icon to nodes

Tags: image, graph, nodes, networkx

I can`t assign image icons to nodes.

I try to get something like this image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5mbH.png)

**This is part of the code
**
`

```
    # libraries
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import networkx as nx
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.image as mpimg
    import PIL

    # Image URLs for graph nodes
    icons = {
        "DDBB server": "DDBB_icon.png",
        "router": "router_icon.png",
        "application server": "server_icon.png",
        "web server": "web_server_icons.png",
       "balancer": "balancer_load_icon.png",        
    }

    # Load images
    images = {k: PIL.Image.open(fname) for k, fname in icons.items()}

    #Assign icon images to nodes

    sistema = pd.read_csv("AppColombia.csv")

    #Origen
    for n in sistema['Tipo_Origen']:
        if n == 'application server':  
            G.nodes(n, image=images["application server"])               
        elif n == 'web server':       
            G.nodes(n, image=images["web server"])
        elif n == 'balancer':
            G.nodes(n, image=images["balancer"])
        elif n == 'DDBB server':          
            G.nodes(n, image=images['DDBB server'])
        else:
            G.nodes(n, image=images["router"])
```

**But, I received following error**

---

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[72], line 15
     13     G.nodes(n, image=images["balancer"])
     14 elif n == 'DDBB server':          
---> 15     G.nodes(n, image=images['DDBB server'])
     16 else:
     17     G.nodes(n, image=images["router"])

TypeError: NodeView.__call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'image'
```

I want to assign icons to each node in order they show it in a graph